# get data from DataGridView (data taken from excel) and display it on vb.net Chart

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, vb.net-2010

I ask for help!!

here I use vb.net, I take data from excel and display it to DataGridView, and after that I want to display it to the Chart here I have trouble to retrieve data from the DataGridView table to display the Chart ..

How do I display the chart with data taken from the DataGridView ... ??

I give a look from me for you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yMt.png)

Comment: You probably loaded the data from the excel file into a datatable; that's where your data lives, not in the datagridview.

Comment: o how should i load data from excel and display it in datagridview and connect datagridview with chart?

Do I have to save it in the database / by changing my method earlier ??

thank you......

Comment: Reading the data from Excel into a `DataTable` is the correct approach.  What you're being told is that the grid is NOT the source for the chart.  The grid and the chart are unrelated.  The `DataTable` is the source for BOTH the grid and the chart.  If you don't know how to import data from Excel into a `DataTable` then you need to search for that.  It's very common and information is easy to find.  Likewise, finding information on displaying data from a `DataTable` into a `DataGridView` or a chary is easy to find. Now you know what to look for, you need to look for it.

Comment: thank you very much ... you have helped open my logic